# RTK Mutation Query causing an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

```
const [createLinkTokenTrigger, createLinkTokenResult] = useCreateLinkTokenMutation();

createLinkTokenTrigger({ productType }, { skip: !isSubscriber });
```

Does using RTK mutation trigger need to be put in a UseEffect()? It solves my problem of infinite render loop but I didn't see useEffect being used in examples and wondering if something else might be wrong with my code.

When I had same mutation query as regular RTK get query this didn't happen. But I recently switched it to a mutation as it's a POST request.

Comment: can share your code in more details?

Comment: That's really all there is. I have that code in a child react component above the return(<JSX>); Where you normally declare all the const variables and functions.

Answer (score 2):

A mutation will execute the moment you execute the `trigger` function. You definitely cannot call that in a render function, just like any other side effect.
You probably also should only put it into a `useEffect` only in edge cases and usually call it in event handlers like `onClick` - after all, it will trigger a change on the server and that should not only happen because the user has a webpage open, but because the user did some kind of interaction.